# What is the ConnectionString to connect MySQL db with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am working on to connect my App form `VB.Net` with `MySQL` table database with this code:

```vb
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim str As String = "data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=tabledb;user id=root;password=password1234"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
    con.Open()

    Dim com As String = "Select * from springdata where rfid_tag='" & Rfid_tagTextBox.Text & "'"
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand(com, con)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()

    If rd.Read() = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Valid username and password")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username and password", caption:="login")
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I run the app gave me this error:

> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was   not accessible. Verify that the instance name
>   is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)

What is the correct `ConnectionString` to use with `MySQL 5.7`.

Comment: You may take a look at the class `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`. Very useful! Second point: you are trying to connect a MySQL-Server with a MSSQL-ServerConnection? This will not work.

Comment: I don't know anything about .NET but maybe you have to set the server port at some point. And of course the connection string is up to your driver so look at the driver documentation

Comment: @Evgeni Enchev I tried the port and not supported!

Comment: I can add the database table in data source as dataset in my VB.NET so it means I have connection established..Right? so the problem with the code syntax maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string below is an [SQL Server connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/):

```
Dim str As String = "data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=tabledb;user id=root;password=password1234"
```

According to [MySQL Connector .NET connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/), you should provide server name, port number (if using different port), database name and credentials like this:

```
Dim str As String = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=tabledb;Uid=root;Pwd=password1234"
```

Also you should use `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` & `MySqlDataReader` instances with parameters instead of value concatenation inside query string (ensure that reference to `MySql.Data.dll` added first):

```vb
Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)
    con.Open()

    Dim com As String = "Select * from springdata where rfid_tag=@tag"

    Using cm As New MySqlCommand(com, con)
        cm.Parameters.Add("@tag", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Rfid_tagTextBox.Text

        Dim rd As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()

        ' Check if any rows exist
        If rd.HasRows = True Then
            ' do something
        Else
            ' do something else
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand & MySqlDataReader not work in my mysql? mysql connector is 6.9.8!

Comment: Make sure the `MySql.Data.dll` referenced in your VB.NET project, also don't forget to include `Using MySql.Data` to use them in your code.

Comment: Yes thank you is working I have to Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient.